# Square roots of quaternions

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

In class we saw that $-1$ has infinitely many square roots in the ring of quaternions. Is it possible to compute the square roots of a given nonreal quaternion? What do they look like?

Comment: Set up the equations for $q^2 = a$, see what you can get out of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With non-real quaternions we can always find two square roots.

You can write any quaternion in the form
$$
q=a+b\vec{u},
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real, and $\vec{u}$ is a unit vector. You probably know that as a quaternion $\vec{u}^2=-1$. Therefore we can treat $\vec{u}$ as if it were the usual imaginary unit $i$ of the complex numbers. So we can use the usual techniques of finding square roots of complex numbers.

Note that with non-real quaternions we only get two square roots. This is because the square of the above quaternion is
$$
q^2=(a^2-b^2)+2ab\vec{u}.
$$
For this to be non-real, we need both $a$ and $b$ to be non-zero. So whenever
$q_1^2=q_2$ for some quaternions $q_1,q_2$ where $q_2\notin\mathbb{R}$, they must both
lie in the same plane, i.e. they must be linear combinations of $1$ and the same unit vector $\vec{u}$. This means that $q_1$ and $q_2$ must belong to the same copy of $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\vec{u}$. As any complex number has only two square roots, the same applies to non-real quaternions because of this.

Comment: Interesting. In the quaternion field $\mathbb{H}$, only negative real numbers have infinitely many square roots, while all other quaternions have only two square roots. Is this true and does this generalize to $n$-th roots?

Comment: @ZhuoranHe I think that the above argument applies to $n$th roots of non-real quaternions as well. But if $n>2$ there are infinitely many $n$th roots of unity in $\Bbb{H}$: to each unit vector $\vec{u}$ we have $n-1$ non-real $n$th roots of unity in $\Bbb{R}\oplus\Bbb{R}\vec{u}$. Therefore all reals have infinitely many $n$th roots in $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: I get it. Whenever there's symmetry breaking, e.g. $\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$, $1^{1/3}=1, e^{\pm2\pi i/3}$ in $\mathbb{C}$, quaternions would say that the $\pm i$ is in fact an infinite number of directions $ai+bj+ck\in\mathbb{H}$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Comment: I think there should be a "where" in between $q_2,q_2$ where it says "$q_1,q_2,q_2\in\mathbb{R}$." I can't make the edit due to the character minimum on edits.

Comment: Thanks @j0equ1nn. Such details are anything but clear to me.